# How to change parent element properties by his child using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

I would like to know how to access a parent element when it doesn't have any identifier. Typically I want to do the following:

```html
<td>
     <a title="mySweetTitle"/>
</td>
```

Access the "td" using his "a" child to modify his properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `parentElement` property https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement

example:

```
document.getElementById('your_id').parentElement
```

in your case you can use

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].parentElement
```

Comment: I'll accept yout answer in 9 min. thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you:

```
$("a").bind("click" , function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer ! Unfortunetely I need to access it without any event happening on the page.

Comment: $('a').parent(); or better with a class:  $('a.myelement').parent();

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for ist $(this).parent() look at my example
i hope it helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().append("<button>test2</button>");
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Test Umgebung</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div>
   <button class="test">test</button>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: with  $(this).parent() you select parent element of button ( <div> container ) if you  use $(this).parent().parent() => you will select <body>